# Any scratch disks available in Photoshop 2017 mac

Tags: hard-drive, mac, adobe-photoshop, scratch

Can you help me? I have installed photoshop to my macbook and when i’m working it begins to write “Any scratch disk available” and really, when i look at Preferences - Scratch disk there’s nothing disk to choice. What can i do, what’s bad? Thanks

Comment: Try holding Cmd/opt as you launch PS. That should present a choice before it starts up.

Comment: Info on Photoshop and [scratch disks](https://macpaw.com/how-to/clear-your-scratch-disk)

Comment: Yes, thanks, i did it but for choice there’s only “Startup” i chose that, now it’s for now running, but i think it’s still so slow, when i crop for example and when i go to Preferences -> Scratch disks, still nothing is here. So i don’t know if it’s right.

Comment: How many disks should you have choose from? If you only have a single Mac volume, the regular boot drive 'Macintosh HD', then that's the only choice you'll get. You will get better performance if your scratch disk isn't your boot drive, & especially if it isn't a tiny drive & almost full. SSD fares no better than HD once nearly full.

Comment: Yes, i have only one disk Macintosh HD, and only Startup to choice, but when i choice it works very bad and very slow how i wrote. I have 40 gb free space on this disk, but when i’m working in photoshop, mac writes that disk is full, when i quit photoshop, again 40 gb. I tried to connect external hdd but it’s not possible use it because is not in choice.

Comment: You should have included that information in your question - it would have saved 7 days of comments. What format is the external drive? It must be GUID/HFS+ for Photoshop to use it.

Comment: But the external drive i tried just now, first not. No it was FAT32. That i don’t know.